# Calling a python script within another one

Tags: python

I have seen a couple of question related to my issue but haven't been able to get an answer.

In my program I have a .txt file that needs to be converted to PDF.
I came across this script that does the same, https://code.activestate.com/recipes/189858-python-text-to-pdf-converter/

I have imported this into my program, but I am not sure how to call and pass my txt file so that it converts it to PDF.

.txt to .pdf converter script name is txttopdf.py i have imported it as import txttopdf and it is present in the same directory

Last part of my program is trying to convert the .txt to .pdf but it gives me a Syntax error.
Below is my program
        import sqlite3 
        import platform
        import sys
        import os
        import re
        import time
        import smtplib
        import mimetypes
        import txttopdf
        from datetime import datetime
        from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
        from email import encoders
        from email.message import Message

```
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText
    ipstr = "unknown"
    errorstr = "unknown"
    gtstr = "unknown"

    print "reading the file"

    linuxpath = raw_input("Enter the path")

    txt_file = open(linuxpath,"r")   
    countlines = 0
    if os.stat("lastline.txt").st_size == 0:
    for line in open(linuxpath):                                        
      pattern = re.compile('(([2][5][0-5]\.)|([2][0-4][0-9]\.)|([0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]\.)){3}'+'(([2][5][0-5])|([2][0-4][0-9])|([0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]))|[\d.]+|\:\:\d|[\w\.]+')
   #([\d.]+)[\s-]+\s+"([A-Z]+)\s+(.+?)"\s+([\s\d]+)')\[([\d\/A-Za-z: -]+)\]
   iprgex = pattern.search(line)
   #print "hi"
   countlines = countlines + 1
   if iprgex:
      ips = iprgex.start()
      ipe = iprgex.end()
      ipstr = line[ips:ipe]
      #print "hi again"
      #print ipstr

   pattern = re.compile('[\d]+\/[A-Za-z]+\/[\d]+')
   #('\[([\d\/A-Za-z: -]+)\]')
   datergex = pattern.search(line)
   #print "hi"
   if datergex:
      dates = datergex.start()
      datee = datergex.end()
      datestr = line[dates:datee]
      #countlines = countlines + 1
      #print "hi again"
      #print datestr
      monthstr = datestr[3:6]
      #print monthstr
      if monthstr == "Jan":
         date_chnge = datestr.replace("Jan","01")
      elif monthstr == "Feb":
         date_chnge = datestr.replace("Feb","02")
      elif monthstr == "Mar":
         date_chnge = datestr.replace("Mar","03")
         #print "am here"
        #print datestr
  elif monthstr == "Apr":
         date_chnge = datestr.replace("Apr","04")
  elif monthstr == "May":
         date_chnge = datestr.replace("May","05")
  elif monthstr == "Jun":
         date_chnge = datestr.replace("Jun","06")
  elif monthstr == "Jul":
         date_chnge = datestr.replace("Jul","07")
  elif monthstr == "Aug":
         date_chnge = datestr.replace("Aug","08")
  elif monthstr == "Sep":
         date_chnge = datestr.replace("Sep","09")
  elif monthstr == "Oct":
         date_chnge = datestr.replace("Oct","10")
  elif monthstr == "Nov":
         date_chnge = datestr.replace("Nov","11")
  elif monthstr == "Dec":
         date_chnge = datestr.replace("Dec","12")

   #print date_chnge
   dt_day = date_chnge[0:2]
   dt_month = date_chnge[3:5]
   dt_year = date_chnge[6:]

   new_date = dt_year + '-' + dt_month + '-' + dt_day

   pattern = re.compile('\:[\d]+\:[\d]+\:[\d]+')
   #('\[([\d\/A-Za-z: -]+)\]')
   timergex = pattern.search(line)
   #print "hi"
   if timergex:
      times = timergex.start()
      timee = timergex.end()
      timestr = line[times:timee]
      #countlines = countlines + 1
      #print "hi again"
      #print timestr
   extract_time = timestr[1:]
   datestring = new_date + ' ' + extract_time
   dt = datetime.strptime(datestring, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
   #print dt.year, dt.month, dt.day

   pattern = re.compile('"([A-Z]+)\s+(.+?)"|"\-"')
   getrgex = pattern.search(line)
   #print line
   if getrgex:
      gts = getrgex.start()
      gte = getrgex.end()
      gtstr = line[gts:gte]
      #countlines = countlines + 1
      #print "hi again"
      #print gtstr

   pattern = re.compile('200|401|403|404|412|500|302')
   errorrgex = pattern.search(line)
   #print "hi"
   if errorrgex:
      errors = errorrgex.start()
      errore = errorrgex.end()
      errorstr = line[errors:errore]
      #countlines = countlines + 1
      #print "hi again"
      #print errorstr

   file = open('parse1.txt','a')
   file.write(ipstr + datestr +timestr + gtstr + errorstr + "\n")
    #Analysing the get request
   print countlines
   #print ipstr,dt,gtstr,errorstr
   with open('ALLINONE.txt','r') as f:
        for cheatsheetline in f:
    indexvalue = gtstr.strip().find(cheatsheetline.strip())
    #print gtstr
    if indexvalue > 0:
        #print indexvalue
        file = open('CAUTION.txt','a')
            file.write(ipstr + datestr +timestr + gtstr + errorstr + "\n")
    #break
    file.close()    

   lastlinefile = open('lastline.txt','w+')
   lastlinefile.write(line)
   #this part should convert the txt file CAUTION.txt to PDF
   #txttopdf.main()
   txttopdf CAUTION.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is via [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor):

**Example:**

```
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE,, STDOUT


PYTEXT2PDF = "/path/to/pytext2pdf"


def convert(filename):
    print("Converting {} to PDF".format(filename))

    p = Popen(
        [sys.executable, PYTEXT2PDF, filename],
        stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT
    )

    stdout, _ = p.communicate()

    print(stdout)


convert("filename.txt")
```

By the looks of it; [`pyText2Pdf`](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/189858-python-text-to-pdf-converter/) will convert the Text file to PDF and name the output file the same "basenaem" as the input file with the extension of `.pdf`.